# Using mysqldump on windows

Tags: sql, gzip, mysql

I'm trying to do mysqldump using the xampp shell. but when I use gzip it gives me an error it says: 'gzip' is not recognized as amn internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I'm putting in

```
mysqldump -u root -p database | gzip -9 > C:\database_bu.sql.gz
```

Comment: Do you have gzip installed? This is standard on many POSIX-type installations (Linux, BSD, OS X, etc.) but not present by default on Windows.

Comment: I have Gzip.pm under xampp library. Any process i have to install gzip?

Comment: Gzip is a command-line tool and also a library included in many things. That's the Perl module, it's of no help here. You need a `gzip.exe` somewhere in your path for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after the response from tadman I was able to resolve it. 
I installed gzip by going to this site: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

I made sure it installed the program on C: and I altered my code to the one below and it worked.

```
mysqldump -u root -p database | C:\GnuWin32\bin\gzip -9 > C:\database_bu.sql.gz
```